# iOS 11 prefersLargeTitles Weird Transition

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, ios11

So I'm having a weird issue with the new large titles in iOS 11. Instead of me trying to badly and confusingly explain the issue here is a 10-second screen recording of what is happening:

[Screen recording of issue on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1LmvoNSPzEI)

As you can see there is a weird black bar that appears when transitioning between a view controller that has

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
```

And one that is set to `.always`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Before the transition set this:

```
self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .white
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pranav, fixed my issue!

Comment: If you're navbar is a different color, instead of setting it's backgroundColor to white, set it to that color

Comment: In which method shall I implement this?

Answer (score 3):

As Pranav said, the issue here is the background colour of the navigation controller's view, however, changing that from a child view controller is not the perfect way to do it.

Instead, a better way is to subclass `UINavigationController` and in the `viewDidLoad()` set the

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
  super.viewDidLoad()
  view.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

Then, just use your custom subclass rather than the standard `UINavigationController`. This way, you only ever need this code in one place.