# Navigation Bar black line with Large title

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, large-title

Thanks for taking the time to read.

Firstly, let me say that I have tried to do my due diligence in searching for a solution to the problem, but to no avail, and it is stressing me out! So, if someone finds an answer could you please point me in the direction :)

The problem I am facing is to do with the black line appearing underneath the Navigation Bar. Now, I am very much aware of the setting a default image/shadow image property of the navigation bar to correct this, and as such, I created my own extension to implement it (shown below)

```
    func hideHairline(_ state:Bool) {
    if state {
        self.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)
    }else{
        self.setBackgroundImage(UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundImage(for: UIBarMetrics.default), for:UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.shadowImage = nil

    }
}
```

However, something seems to be misbehaving, and I am getting a black line appearing underneath my navigation bar (see below)

[image: navbar with line]
Whats more strange, is that the simulator does not show this line on the same screen. The simulator is set to be pixel accurate. (as shown below)

[image: navbar without line]

I think it may have something to do with the way I am changing from a previous VC. I am changing from having the navigation bar hidden, to shown, and it is set to `prefersLargeTitles`. Now, if I set the navigation bar, not to use the large titles, the black line doesn't show. Also, if I push to the next view controller, and then pop back, the line is not there (on the pushed controller, or the newly presented popped)

At this point, I am mainly just wondering why this is happening? I mean, I must have done something wrong. I wrote a setup extension, just to keep the code away from the VC, probably isn't the best coding practice, but hey!

```
        self.hideHairline(true)
    self.titleTextAttributes =  [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : Constants.navigationBarTextColor]
    self.largeTitleTextAttributes = self.titleTextAttributes
    self.barTintColor = Constants.navigationBar
    self.tintColor = Constants.navigationBarTint
    self.isTranslucent = false
    self.backgroundColor = Constants.navigationBar
    self.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

The `Constants` is a class that holds all of the static variables in my app, such as colo(u)rs. Have I just made some stupid mistake, or is there a bug with large titles?

If you need any further information, please, just ask :)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, after taking a break for the evening, I have found a solution. I am going to leave this post up, for anyone else that might encounter a similar problem in the future.

It is to do with the view of the `UINavigationController` itself. I found another stack overflow post that answered it ([link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46217241/ios-11-preferslargetitles-weird-transition))

All I had to do was:

```
self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .white
```

change the colo(u)r to whatever you need it to be.

Simple solution, and I cannot believe it took me so long to figure out.

All the best.